# ConstraintLayout, adding constraints moves all my elements

Tags: android

I am trying to design a custom field for a recyclerview, but I encountered problems regarding the ConstraintLayout. Using the design, I moved all my design elements where I wanted, but as soon as I add any kind of constraint (using Infer Contstraints or writing directly in the XML file, all of the elements move in completely different positions which are in no way how I positioned them. Here is my XML code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_row_selector"
android:padding="8dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

<!-- Thumbnail Image -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="87dp"
    android:layout_height="89dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

<!-- Movie Title -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="216dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/title"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="90dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

<!-- Rating -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/rating"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="90dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="85dp" />

<!-- Genre -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/genre"
    android:layout_width="334dp"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:textColor="@color/genre"
    android:textSize="@dimen/genre"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="114dp" />

<!-- Release Year -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/releaseYear"
    android:layout_width="129dp"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:textColor="@color/year"
    android:textSize="@dimen/year"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="172dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="85dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btnBookOption"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:src="@drawable/book_add_touch"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="304dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="39dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/author"
    android:layout_width="195dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="90dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="39dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is how I am trying to make my list look:

[image]

And here is how it looks after I add constraints

[image]

How can I add the constraints, but make the layout look like in the first pic at the same time? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create the constraints properly. You can [check the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/) for more details.

Be aware that the `tools` annotated parameters are only for [development preview](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes). When you run your app the compiler removes those parameters.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <!-- Thumbnail Image -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="89dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

    <!-- Movie Title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/thumbnail"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/thumbnail"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="90dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

    <!-- Rating -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/thumbnail"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/author"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="90dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="85dp" />

    <!-- Genre -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/genre"
        android:layout_width="334dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="114dp" />

    <!-- Release Year -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/releaseYear"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/rating"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="172dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="85dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnBookOption"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/releaseYear"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/author"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="304dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="39dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btnBookOption"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/thumbnail"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="90dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="39dp" />

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: That was really helpful. Thank you for the code and for the documentation :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <!-- Thumbnail Image -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="89dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:background="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

    <!-- Movie Title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="216dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/thumbnail"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/first_names" />

    <!-- Rating -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/rating"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/releaseYear"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnBookOption"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/us_zipcodes" />

    <!-- Genre -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/genre"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/genre"
        android:textSize="@dimen/genre"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rating"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/cities" />

    <!-- Release Year -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/releaseYear"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:textColor="@color/year"
        android:textSize="@dimen/year"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btnBookOption"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rating"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnBookOption"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/date/ddmmyy" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/btnBookOption"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/btnBookOption"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnBookOption"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/full_names" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnBookOption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/author"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        tools:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```